# Bluring image with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to blur image. I am using convert command to change format image from .bmp to pbm and then again to bmp

My idea was to for loop each pixel of image, compute avarage of current and local pixels and distribute the avarage

Unfortunately if I am trying to convert the image to bmp, I get error:

```
convert: improper image header `newFile.ppm' @ error/pnm.c/ReadPNMImage/282.
convert: no images defined `newFile.bmp' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

My script look like this:
GNU nano 2.5.3                 File: blur.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

name=$(echo $1 | cut -d'.' -f1)
echo $name
name="$name.ppm"
echo $name
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}
/^.*/{
    for(i=0; i < NF -5; i++) {
        avarage=(($i + $($i+1) + $($i+2))/3)
        printf $avarage" "
        if(i > 100) {printf $i >> "newFile.ppm" }
        else {
            printf $avarage" " >> "newFile.ppm"
            printf $avarage" " >> "newFile.ppm"
            printf $avarage" " >> "newFile.ppm"
        }
    }
}' $name
```

Comment: `awk` sounds like a perverse choice for something like this - if you're using ImageMagick's `convert` utility, can't you blur the image directly? See [Blurring Images (low-pass filtering)](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/#blurring_images) for example.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is a poor tool for doing image processing.

The issue comes from not writing a proper PPM image header to the output file. You also disregard the header in the input file. If the PPM image is not of type `P3` (ASCII encoded RGB), `P2` (ASCII encoded graymap) or `P1` (ASCII encoded black-and-white), you also can't read it as you normally read a text file (as it will be binary).

The format of this header is described, for example, in [the Wikipedia article on the Netpbm format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PPM_example).  The example given in the article is

```
P3
3 2
255
# The part above is the header
# "P3" means this is a RGB color image in ASCII
# "3 2" is the width and height of the image in pixels
# "255" is the maximum value for each color
# The part below is image data: RGB triplets
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

Note that in this example, there are three pixels per line although the later examples in the article shows that newlines are not significant and that the pixels' RGB values may be normalized:

The same image:

```
P3
# The same image with width 3 and height 2,
# using 0 or 1 per color (red, green, blue)
3 2 1
1 0 0   0 1 0   0 0 1
1 1 0   1 1 1   0 0 0
```

The same image:

```
P3 3 2 1  1 0 0   0 1 0   0 0 1  1 1 0   1 1 1   0 0 0
```

Furthermore, your loop ignores the last three RGB values on each line (or the three last pixels if the image is grayscale or black and white).